# Expanded button on whole stack view?

Tags: swift, stackview

I drag out the stack view onto view controller and I tried out to put them a few objects like button , label and so on. My problem is: When I drag the button onto stack view, the button is completely resized and fill the whole stack view. What's going on?

Answer (score 0):

When you drag the button onto stack view, then stack view will resize. it's normal. try to add another component onto stack view. it will resize again according  those all component that you added.

Comment: Txh, You are right . I had to see some tutorial to understand that .tkanks